# Can't Install Steam libc.so.6

Tags: software-center, steam

Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6

I installed steam from the software center.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```